# Homework: finding Big-Oh for code fragments

Tags: big-o

To be up front with everyone, this is for a homework assignment.  I don't expect anyone to provide out and out answers for me, this is more to check that I'm understanding things correctly or to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've been given some fragments of code to determine what Big-Oh would be of them.  Each is dealing with for loops, however the last two that we were given are throwing me off a bit.  The first:

```
   sum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) //1
         for (j = 0; j < i * i; j++) //2
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++) //3
               sum++;
```

I think that Big-Oh of this would be O(n^4).  #1 will run n times, #2 will run n^2 times, and #3 will run n times, giving me n^4.  However, when I write this properly in C++ and give n values of 10, 100 and 1000 (per my assignment), n = 10 returns 7524 (good, less than 10,000) n = 100 returns a value of 975,002,490 while the upper bound would be 100,000,000.  Obviously, I'm off somewhere in my analysis of the loops, but I'm not quite sure where.  Not sure what n = 1000 will return, since my computer has been crunching away at it for a while and doesn't appear to be ready to give me an answer yet.

The second fragment is as follows:

```
   sum = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) //1
         for (j = 0; j < i * i; j++) //2
            if (j % i == 0) //3
               for (k = 0; k < j; k++) //4
                  sum++;
```

I believe I can safely ignore the if statement since its runtime would be the running time of the test plus its contents, meaning I would again come up with O(n^4).

Comment: If the j loop is supposed to run n^2 times according to your analysis, wouldn't the k loop also run n^2 times by the same argument? Asymptotic analysis always ignores the constant factors for the most part, which might be an issue in realistic scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Well Im not a big O expert but I know for loops and some maths so I will try help you a bit.

When you consider your statement " #1 will run n times, #2 will run n^2 times, and #3 will run n times, giving me n^4" it is only partially correct.. Yes the numbers is almost correct if you run the loops separatly. But consider an example of n = 4... First #1 will run 4 times, but for each iteration of loop number #1 loops number #2 will run i*i times... so..

First when i = 0 #2 will run 0 times.. (j < 0*0) 
Then when i = 1 #2 will run 1 time (j < 1*1) 
Then when i = 2 #2 loop will run 4 times (j < 2*2) 
and when i = 3 #2 will run 9 times  (j < 3*3)

so in total #2 will run 14 times. (0 + 1 + 4 + 9 ) and 4^4 is not 14. And this also escalates to the #3 loops.

As you said that you are not interested in a direct answer I hope this helps you understand the for loops a bit better.